# Select() using and operator doesnt returns a value similar to or operator when querying datatable C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to select records in which the rows have both the "ID" field is equal to the "id" value value and the "Date" field is equal to the date field "Log Date" in a different table "dv".

The problem is that the returned records in "foundID" are not processing the rows in AND manner but it is processing it as if it was OR.

```
for (int id = 0; id < 200; id++)
{
    var foundID = from r in dv.AsEnumerable()
    orderby r.Field<string>("Log Date")
    where r.Field<int>("User ID") ==  id
    select r;

    foreach (var row in foundID)
    {
        var foundDate = overtime.Select("ID = '" + id 
        + "' AND 'Log Date' = '"+row.Field<string>("Log Date")+"'");

        if(foundDate.Count() == 0){
            Rowq["ID"] = row.Field<int>("User ID");
            Rowq["Date"] = row.Field<string>("Log Date");
            overtime.Rows.Add(Rowq);
            Rowq = overtime.NewRow();

        }
        else { 
            continue; 
        }
    }
        id++;
}
```

the input "dv" table looks like this:

```
 User ID        Name     Log Date     Log Time  FKey
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/16    09:03:13    F1
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/16    17:02:20    F2
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/18    08:38:42    F1
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/18    16:55:02    F2
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/19    09:05:21    F1
0000000004    Name2    2014/10/01    00:07:09    F2
0000000004    Name2    2014/10/01    15:46:49    F1
0000000004    Name2    2014/10/02    00:09:52    F2
```

the output "overtime" must look like this:

```
    ID         Name        Date          F1           F2      None

     2        Name1    2014/10/18       time        time      time
     2        Name1    2014/10/19       time        time      time
     4        Name2    2014/10/01       time        time      time
     4        Name2    2014/10/01       time        time      time
     4        Name2    2014/10/02       time        time      time
  etc..
```

As you can notice, each ID has several records one for each date. but the output table "overtime" returns two records for each ID with one random date.

I have fixed a problem in the first post about the increment but still it now displays two rows for each ID. I want to merge each row with its counter part rows of the same ID and Date. the function of 
    var foundDate = overtime.Select("ID = '" + id 
        + "' AND 'Log Date' = '"+row.Field("Log Date")+"'");
doesn't return a record although the overtime table contains a matching record of ID and Date

Comment: What is name of F1 and F2 values column? Do all ids have both F1 and F2 values? Is there other values in this column? Can some id have several names for same date, or several F1 values for same date/name?

Comment: I have edited the labels of the Table. FKey can contain F1, F2 , and None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it should be

```
var foundDate = overtime.Select("ID = '" + id 
                + "' AND [Log Date] = '"+row.Field<string>("Log Date")+"'");
```

Note that [Log Date] instead of 'Log Date'

Secondly, you're incrementing id after logging an overtime, but then continue inserting rows explicitly matching the previous id.

Either, the incrementation is wrong, or you should break out of the loop after incrementing.

Take a look at the following, it provides the correct data in the overtime table

```
void Main()
{
    var overtime = new DataTable();
    overtime.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    overtime.Columns.Add("Log Date", typeof(string));
    overtime.Columns.Add("F1", typeof(string));
    overtime.Columns.Add("F2", typeof(string));

    var dv = new DataTable();
    dv.Columns.Add("User ID", typeof(int));
    dv.Columns.Add("Log Date", typeof(string));
    dv.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
    dv.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));

    var row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000002;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/16";
    row["Type"] = "F1";
    row["Time"] = "09:03:13";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000002;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/16";
    row["Type"] = "F2";
    row["Time"] = "17:02:20";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000002;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/18";
    row["Type"] = "F1";
    row["Time"] = "08:38:42";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000002;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/19";
    row["Type"] = "F2";
    row["Time"] = "16:55:02";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000002;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/19";
    row["Type"] = "F1";
    row["Time"] = "09:05:21";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000004;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/01";
    row["Type"] = "F2";
    row["Time"] = "00:07:09";

    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000004;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/01";
    row["Type"] = "F1";
    row["Time"] = "15:46:49";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dv.NewRow();
    row["User ID"] = 0000000004;
    row["Log Date"] = "2014/10/02";
    row["Type"] = "F2";
    row["Time"] = "00:09:52 ";
    dv.Rows.Add(row);

    foreach(var personGrouping in dv.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("User ID")))
    {
        foreach(var dayGrouping in personGrouping.GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Log Date")))
        {
            //Now we need to find F1 and F2
            var orderedTime = dayGrouping.OrderBy(dg => dg.Field<string>("Time")).ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < orderedTime.Count; i++)
            {

                var f1 = orderedTime[i];
                if (orderedTime.Count <= i + 1) //Either F2 doesn't exist, or it exists on another date
                    continue;

                var f2 = orderedTime[i + 1];

                if (!overtime.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any (dr => dr.Field<int>("ID") == personGrouping.Key && dr.Field<string>("Log Date") == dayGrouping.Key))
                {
                    row = overtime.NewRow();
                    row["ID"] = personGrouping.Key;
                    row["Log Date"] = dayGrouping.Key;
                    row["F1"] = f1.Field<string>("Time");
                    row["F2"] = f2.Field<string>("Time");
                    overtime.Rows.Add(row);

                }

            }

        }
    }

    overtime.Dump();
}
```

This produces the output:

```
2    2014/10/16    09:03:13    17:02:20
2    2014/10/19    09:05:21    16:55:02
4    2014/10/01    00:07:09    15:46:49
```

If F2 falls on the next day (which happens in your example data):

```
0000000002    Name1    2014/10/19    09:05:21    F1
0000000004    Name2   2014/10/01    00:07:09    F2
```

The entry is not added. You'll have to modify the above to your business requirements

Comment: Thank you very much. your Code works perfectly. As for dates that continue over the next day, I am trying to figure it out although the example you provided involves two different IDs. I tried to fix the ID increment as I edited my question but still I had a problem. I am going to use the code you have written. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works. As for the different dates - I copied the wrong ones - actually, the last two rows in your sample data overflow to the next day (ID: 4, F1: 2014/10/01 - 15:46:49 , F2: 2014/10/02 - 00:09:52)